# How to concatenate strings

Tags: atmega328, display

I am new to the Arduino platform so please bear with me. I have a program to display rolling text on a LED matrix which is for the Tinyduino platform

```c++
#include "Charliplexing.h"
#include "Font.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

void setup()
{
  LedSign::Init();
}

static char test[]="HELLO";

void loop()
{
  for (int8_t x=DISPLAY_COLS, i=0;; x--) {
    LedSign::Clear();
    for (int8_t x2=x, i2=i; x2<DISPLAY_COLS;) {
      int8_t w = Font::Draw(test[i2], x2, 0);
      x2 += w, i2 = (i2+1)%strlen(test);
      if (x2 <= 0)  // off the display completely?
        x = x2, i = i2;
    }
    delay(80);
  }
}
```

Then I have some code to read temperature and humidity data for the same Tinyduino platform

```c++
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SI7021.h>

SI7021 sensor;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.print("Initializing sensor... ");
  if(!sensor.begin()){
    Serial.println("Sensor not found!");
    while(true);
  }
  Serial.println("Success!");
}

void loop()
{
  int celcius=sensor.getCelsiusHundredths()/100;
  int relativeHumidity=sensor.getHumidityPercent();
  Serial.print(celcius);
  Serial.print(" deg Celsius\t");
  Serial.print(relativeHumidity);
  Serial.println("% relative humidity");

  delay(500);
}
```

I am trying to integrate this together so that Arduino reads the temperature and humidity sensor data and then displays it on the LED matrix as text. I have some code that is integrated from the above two examples

```c++
#include "Charliplexing.h"
#include "Font.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SI7021.h>

SI7021 sensor;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.print("Initializing sensor... ");
  if(!sensor.begin()){
    Serial.println("Sensor not found!");
    while(true);
  }
  Serial.println("Success!");
  LedSign::Init();
}

static char test[100]="";

void loop()
{
  int celcius=sensor.getCelsiusHundredths()/100;
  int relativeHumidity=sensor.getHumidityPercent();
  test=celcius+" deg celsius"+" "+relativeHumidity+" relative humidity";

  for (int8_t x=DISPLAY_COLS, i=0;; x--) {
    LedSign::Clear();
    for (int8_t x2=x, i2=i; x2<DISPLAY_COLS;) {
      int8_t w = Font::Draw(test[i2], x2, 0);
      x2 += w, i2 = (i2+1)%strlen(test);
      if (x2 <= 0)  // off the display completely?
        x = x2, i = i2;
    }
    delay(80);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

Here is the error message that the IDE throws out

```
test:28: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'

 test=celcius+" deg celsius"+" "+relativeHumidity+" relative humidity";
                             ^

Using library LOL in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\LOL (legacy)
Using library Wire at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\Wire
Using library Temp in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Temp (legacy)
exit status 1
invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this error is welcome.

Comment: Good first question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sprintf to format a string.

You have to change:

```
test=celcius+" deg celsius"+" "+relativeHumidity+" relative humidity";
```

for

```
sprintf(test,"%d deg celsius %d relative humidity",celcius,relativeHumidity);
```

Comment: I have the code working but the sensor does not refresh the data and displays it only once. Do you see any reason why that would happen

Comment: In this line there is no condition: `for (int8_t x=DISPLAY_COLS, i=0;; x--)`. More info: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "add" character arrays like that. You may try to use a
`String` object instead, as these do support the `+` operator as a way
to concatenate them:

```c++
String message = (String(celcius) + " deg Celcius, "
               + relativeHumidity + " relative humidity");
const char *c_message = message.c_str();
```

And then you use `c_message` in place of your `test` variable.
Note that only the first element (`celcius` here) needs to be explicitly
converted to a `String` object. The other conversions happen implicitly.

**Edit**: Updated the code to avoid using the internal state of a
(possibly destroyed) temporary object.

Comment: -1 This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @TomKnapen: Oops! Updated the code.